# python string compare - any char inside string

Tags: python, regex, string, compare

I need to compare two strings but should be able to specify substrings within the string which I want to ignore while matching. I want to use x in places which I want to ignore. So for instance, if I have a T**T, I want it to match TAAT or a TabT.

```
str1 = 'T**T'
str2 = 'TDDT'
str3 = 'TXXT'

if str2 == str1:
    print('OK')
if str3 == str1:
    print('OK')
```

Thanks!

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: It is already solved. Somebody modified it (maybe I was not clear enough).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `zip()` with `all()`:

```
def are_equal(string1, string2):
    return all(x == y or '*' in x + y for x, y in zip(string1, string2))
```

For each character in `string1` and `string2`, represented by `x` and `y`, we check if they are equal or if one or both of them is `*`.  If all of the checks are `True`, we return `True`.  Otherwise, `False`.

Comment: Thanks! I will look further into all and zip to understand this better!